# How to get eBay auction end time from number?

Tags: php, timestamp

I am trying to scrape information from for eBay search [result](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_dmd=1&_sacat=0&_nkw=box&rt=nc&LH_Auction=1)

In source I see

```
<span class="MINUTES timeMs" timeMs="1388791906000"></span>
<span class="HOURS timeMs" timeMs="1388797706000"></span>
```

What format is timeMs value? I want to convert it to timestamp, but I don't recognize for what these numbers stands for?

P.S. Don't want to use eBay API!

Comment: Looks like milliseconds

Comment: Time in milliseconds. Why don't you want to use an eBay API?

Comment: Scraping is a very poor practice. Why don't you want to use the API?

Comment: It was time in ms, but needed to sub string to 10 symbols instead of 13. Just learning php, later maybe will use API, right now it looks kinda difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timeMs` is in Unix EpochTime.

Once timeMs is stored in `$timeMs`, then use the following:

```
$date_time = new DateTime("@$timeMs");
$formatted_time = $date_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Also, as an alternative to using the DateTime class, you can use:

```
echo date('r', $timeMs); // output as RFC 2822 date - returns local time
echo gmdate('r', $timeMs); // returns GMT/UTC time
```

as explained [here](http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/functions-php.php).